# Extract email content through Airflow

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow, gmail-api

Is there a way I can extract the following information from an email:

1. Subject
2. Sender
3. Receiver
4. Timestamp

Search email based on email cc-ed to it. The email is `gmail`.

I've gone through this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/apache-airflow-automating-the-collection-of-daily-email-attachments-213bc7128d3a) but this is to download attachment.

I only need the above information. Then store in BQ.
How can I achieve this?

So far, this is what I've done:

```
from airflow.operators import IMAPAttachmentOperator

extract_email = IMAPAttachmentOperator(
    imap_conn_id='my_email_conn',
    mailbox='inbox',
    search_criteria={"CC": "some_email@gmail.com"},
    task_id='extract_email_content',
    dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there's no ready made operator so you need to build your own. The bright side is that there seems to be enough logic in Airflow that can be reused or used as guidance. For example here in [IMapHook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/8ae2bb9bfa8cfd62a8ae5f6edabce47800ccb140/airflow/providers/imap/hooks/imap.py#L228-L234) is logic for getting emails and you can then filter them in operator. Other option would be to use `search`, something like `IMapHook().mail_client.search(...)`, reference [search docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.search).

Regarding storing the information in BQ - construct your custom operator to save the required information to BQ using [BigQueryHook.insert_rows](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/8ae2bb9bfa8cfd62a8ae5f6edabce47800ccb140/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py#L188-L196).

You can use can also use [GCSHook.upload](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/8ae2bb9bfa8cfd62a8ae5f6edabce47800ccb140/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/gcs.py#L393-L405) to upload the data to GCS and then use [GCSToBigQueryOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/8ae2bb9bfa8cfd62a8ae5f6edabce47800ccb140/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery.py#L29-L162)